# Kivy screen manager only accepts screen widget

Tags: python, kivy

This is my main code:

```
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.core.window import Window
Window.size = (350,580)

class LoginPage(MDApp):

    def build(self):
        global screen_manager
        screen_manager = ScreenManager()
        screen_manager.add_widget(Builder.load_file("pre-splash.kv"))
        screen_manager.add_widget(Builder.load_file("login.kv"))
        return screen_manager

if __name__ == "__main__":
    LoginPage().run()
```

This is my .kv file:

```
Screen:

    name: "pre-splash"
    MDFloatLayout:
        md_bg_color : 226/255, 0 , 48/255, 1
        Image:
            source:"AppData/Local/Temp/logo-no-background.png"
            size_hint: .26, .26
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgb: 1, 1, 1, 1
                Ellipse:
                    size: 130, 130
                    pos: 110,250
```

Okay, so I am pretty new with Kivy so I do not understand some of the main concepts but this is my .kv code and its giving an error here saying that the screen manager only accepts Screen widget. I have included the main source and the .kv source. I cant seem to find anything out of place in this. I am running kivy 1.1.1 . I am trying to add a splash to my app in this but its giving me this error.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah. ScreenManager only manages screen widgets. ScreenManager will not manage anything other than Screen widget and custom widgets made by Screen.

And there is no point in adding splash screen to your kivy app. Because you have the flexibility to add the splash screen and all that stuff in buildozer.spec file .